# Pi 2, keyboard/mouse not recognized through USB hub

Tags: usb, pi-2, keyboard, mouse

I am trying to get the keyboard and mouse control from a [Startech crash cart adapter](http://www.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/USB-Crash-Cart-Adapter~NOTECONS02X) working smoothly on a Pi 2.

The adapter has an internal USB hub (Alcor, 058F:6254) and behind that a virtual keyboard, mouse, and storage device -- so it should appear to the Pi as a hub with a keyboard, mouse, and (if enabled) a storage device plugged into it. I've read through https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=53832 and have done what I could.

I've got the latest version of everything according to `rpi-update`, kernel is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux unbound-proto-1 4.1.19-v7+ #851 SMP Sat Mar 5 22:58:42 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

So the first thing I did was plug in the adapter right out of the box. The keyboard and mouse were not recognized, although the Pi works fine with a real keyboard and mouse. When I plugged in the adapter, I get:

```
$ dmesg
[  132.364632] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[  132.465121] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6254
[  132.465147] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  132.466846] hub 1-1.5:1.0: USB hub found
[  132.467082] hub 1-1.5:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  132.744659] usb 1-1.5.2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[  132.745223] dwc_otg: DEVICE:000 : update_urb_state_xfer_intr:1435:trimming xfer length
[  132.844646] usb 1-1.5.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  133.054639] usb 1-1.5.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  133.244659] usb 1-1.5.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
[  133.344695] usb 1-1.5.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  133.554641] usb 1-1.5.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  133.744660] usb 1-1.5.2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
[  134.164628] usb 1-1.5.2: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[  134.244665] usb 1-1.5.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
[  134.664646] usb 1-1.5.2: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[  134.664821] usb 1-1.5-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

And `lsusb` shows the hub but not the keyboard / mouse that should be attached to it (the Logitech devices are the real ones, the Alcor hub is the adapter):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub

$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=rtl8192cu, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 7, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
```

Seeing no other option, I then added `dwc_otg.speed=1` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
dwc_otg.speed=1 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
```

After rebooting, I found that the Startech's keyboard and mouse interface now worked fine, but the real keyboard and mouse were no longer recognized. Here's what I got plugging in the Startech after making the above change:

```
$ dmesg
[  234.404780] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 15 using dwc_otg
[  234.505447] usb 1-1.5: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[  234.506146] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6254
[  234.506167] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  234.507320] hub 1-1.5:1.0: USB hub found
[  234.507683] hub 1-1.5:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  234.804794] usb 1-1.5.2: new full-speed USB device number 16 using dwc_otg
[  234.907221] usb 1-1.5.2: New USB device found, idVendor=152a, idProduct=8461
[  234.907247] usb 1-1.5.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  234.907266] usb 1-1.5.2: Product: USB KM          
[  234.907282] usb 1-1.5.2: Manufacturer: NXP SEMICOND 
[  234.907298] usb 1-1.5.2: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[  234.912362] input: NXP SEMICOND  USB KM           as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2/1-1.5.2:1.0/0003:152A:8461.0003/input/input2
[  234.965635] hid-generic 0003:152A:8461.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [NXP SEMICOND  USB KM          ] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5.2/input0
[  234.969975] input: NXP SEMICOND  USB KM           as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2/1-1.5.2:1.1/0003:152A:8461.0004/input/input3
[  234.971755] hid-generic 0003:152A:8461.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [NXP SEMICOND  USB KM          ] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5.2/input1
```

And `lsusb` also shows the devices on the hub now:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 152a:8461  

$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/5p, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 12, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=rtl8192cu, 12M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 15, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 16, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 16, If 1, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Also, here is some more detailed info on the keyboard / mouse, from `lsusb -v`:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 152a:8461  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x152a 
  idProduct          0x8461 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower               10mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode           51 Unknown
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              16
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      85
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              16
```

Interestingly, though, the Startech's virtual storage device works fine through its hub in both cases. So it is not an issue with the hub, it seems to be an issue with the Startech virtual keyboard and mouse hardware.

### TL;DR

So basically, in summary:

- Without `dwc_otg.speed=1`:

  - My real Logitech keyboard/mouse works fine.
  - The Startech hub -> keyboard/mouse doesn't work.
  - The Startech hub -> storage device works fine.
- With `dwc_otg.speed=1`:

  - My real Logitech keyboard/mouse doesn't work.
  - The Startech hub -> keyboard/mouse works fine.
  - The Startech hub -> storage device still works fine.
  - Also wifi feels a bit slower.

How can I make everything work? Why is `dwc_otg.speed=1` allowing the Startech stuff to work but breaking the Logitech stuff, and how can I get it working without setting that option?

Here's a diagram. Red only works with `.speed=1`, yellow only works with `.speed=0`, and green works no matter what the setting is:

[image]

I'm not really sure what's going on. I don't know much about how USB works or what drivers are involved. I've used the Startech device on Windows, Linux, and OS X PCs, on Gumstix, Udoos, and on Beagleboards. The Pi is uniquely troublesome.

Comment: I believe there is a wiki page which lists all compatible USB mice/keyboards. That might be worth a look.

Comment: @DarthVader I found [this](http://www.raspberry-pi.co.uk/2012/06/07/updated-list-of-compatible-usb-keyboards/) for keyboards at least. It also says, *"We have been told that any USB mouse or keyboard that presents itself as a standard HID device should work to some extent"*. The keyboard at least reports HID -> Boot Interface Subclass -> Keyboard. What confuses me is why it works with `dwc_otg.speed=1`.

Comment: It's also strange that `lsusb` doesn't seem to be aware of the vendor/product string even though at some point it is read and echoed to kern.log (`hid-generic ... USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [NXP SEMICOND  USB KM]`). Plus, the issue is unique to the Pi. So I'm not sure what I should be pursuing: Missing drivers, hid driver bugs on the Pi, etc. I'm still trying to find the exact part, NXP makes a bunch of USB controllers used in devices with virtual keyboards and mice (seems like a common chip in various KVM switches). The vendor ID 152A seems bogus though.

Comment: Related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/how-can-dwc-otg-speed-1-be-made-to-work

Comment: So your at a point where both your keyboard and mouse work as expected when connected directly to the Pi's USB ports? Is your USB hub powered, i.e plugs into the mains? Also what are you using to power your Pi? At the moment I see no reason why your set up with the USB hub shouldn't work.

Comment: @Darth Almost. The startech KM works as expected *only* with speed=1. The Logitech devices (directly to pi usb ports) work as expected *only* with speed=0. The startechs usb storage interface works in all cases, so the issue appears to be with the km interface not the hub itself. I need them all to work, ideally with speed=0. The "hub" is internal to the startech device and is powered from the USB port of a laptop. The pi is powered off its microusb port to an AC adapter.

Comment: My point is if your keyboard and mouse work directly with the Pi, is the USB hub really necessary to your set up?

Comment: @Darth The hub is not a physical hub. It's a [Startech KVM adapter](http://www.startech.com/m/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/USB-Crash-Cart-Adapter~NOTECONS02X). It has a hub internally, through which it provides a keyboard, mouse, and storage interface. Internally there's an Alcor hub, an NXP chip for keyboard and mouse, and a storage interface somewhere. There's no way to avoid it. But the hub part seems fine. It's just the keyboard and mouse hardware that's problematic, and only on the Pi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36688/discussion-between-darth-vader-and-jason-c).