# USB devices (Including Internal NIC) got disconnected without a reason

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

I am using raspberry pi 1 B+ model with two USB devices (wifi dongle/Ethernet  )
along with builtin NIC. all the USB devices including builtin NIC getting disconnected from time to time

kernel version is `4.9.35+ #1014 Fri Jun 30 14:34:49 BST 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux`

logs as bellow

```
Dec 12 22:56:37 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [17385.439443] wlan0: authenticate with d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX
Dec 12 22:56:37 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [17385.497462] wlan0: send auth to d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
Dec 12 22:56:37 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [17385.499758] wlan0: authenticated
Dec 12 22:56:37 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [17385.502989] wlan0: associate with d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
Dec 12 22:56:37 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [17385.515521] wlan0: RX AssocResp from d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Dec 12 22:56:37 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [17385.558634] wlan0: associated
Dec 12 23:38:03 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19871.632991] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:487: Not connected
Dec 12 23:38:03 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19871.632991]
Dec 12 23:38:03 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19871.649714] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:487: Not connected
Dec 12 23:38:03 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19871.649714]
Dec 12 23:38:04 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19871.829896] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Dec 12 23:38:04 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19871.829921] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Dec 12 23:38:04 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19871.830302] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
Dec 12 23:38:04 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19871.830390] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Dec 12 23:38:05 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19872.840714] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
Dec 12 23:38:05 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19872.840942] cdc_ether 1-1.2:2.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-20980000.usb-1.2, CDC Ethernet Device
Dec 12 23:38:06 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19873.768350] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
Dec 12 23:38:06 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19873.769099] wlan0: deauthenticating from d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Dec 12 23:38:07 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19875.489966] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
Dec 12 23:38:08 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19875.919846] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Dec 12 23:38:08 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19875.920082] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Dec 12 23:38:08 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.260391] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
Dec 12 23:38:08 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.260415] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Dec 12 23:38:08 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.275809] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
Dec 12 23:38:08 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.275984] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
Dec 12 23:38:08 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.599882] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.730401] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.730424] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.745718] smsc95xx v1.0.5
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.863559] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:22:09:9f
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19876.959958] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.114163] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8050
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.114186] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.114196] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB 10/100 LAN
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.114206] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.114216] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 00E04AXXXXXX
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.137640] cdc_ether 1-1.2:2.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-20980000.usb-1.2, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:e0:4a:39:14:0d
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.239906] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.439916] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.581262] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=760b
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.581285] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.581296] usb 1-1.3: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.581306] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.581315] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1.0
Dec 12 23:38:09 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.679941] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
Dec 12 23:38:10 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.813145] mt7601u 1-1.3:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
Dec 12 23:38:10 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19877.903677] mt7601u 1-1.3:1.0: EEPROM ver:0c fae:00
Dec 12 23:38:10 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19878.274536] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Dec 12 23:38:12 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19880.142227] wlan0: authenticate with d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX
Dec 12 23:38:12 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19880.206526] wlan0: send auth to d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
Dec 12 23:38:12 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19880.208932] wlan0: authenticated
Dec 12 23:38:12 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19880.212005] wlan0: associate with d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
Dec 12 23:38:12 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19880.225188] wlan0: RX AssocResp from d8:d8:66:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Dec 12 23:38:12 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19880.267596] wlan0: associated
Dec 12 23:38:12 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19880.267989] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Dec 12 23:38:14 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19882.236209] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Dec 12 23:38:14 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [19882.237338] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Dec 13 02:35:59 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [30548.180128] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Dec 13 02:35:59 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [30548.183058] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x41E1
Dec 13 02:36:18 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [30566.788249] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link down
Dec 13 02:36:29 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [30578.118764] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x41E1
Dec 13 02:37:54 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [30662.810268] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link down
Dec 13 02:37:56 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [30664.495514] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x4DE1
Dec 13 02:45:14 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [31102.885354] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link down
Dec 13 02:45:16 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [31104.488588] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x4DE1
Dec 13 02:45:17 ibr-1-cmb kernel: [31105.485416] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link down
```

have any thought on this ?

**Update :**

I am facing this only If I connected both wifi adapter and Ethernet usb devices. If I connect only one device it works fine (running without any issue for weeks)

I am using this as IPv6 router to use with hurricane electric's tunnel broker since my ISP does not provides native IPv6 connectivity. wlan0 connected to ISP router and eth connected to my PC. everything went well until I try to connect second ISP router via new Ethernet USB adapter

Comment: What do you use as a power source for your Raspberry-Pi ? Do you use a USB hub to connect multiple devices ? Also you take a look [here](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems)

Comment: @Ephemeral I am using a 1AMP USB power source. No I am not using a USB hub, two USB devices are connect directly to USB ports

Comment: Ok thank you for this additional informations. Have you upgrade your raspbian (I suppose NO because you have a tag `Raspbian stretch`) ? Maybe try [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=192263) : `sudo apt-get update && 
sudo apt-get install firmware-ralink` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? Also, try to disconnect all additional devices from your USB ports and try only with your Wireless adapter (maybe one device connected have a hardware problem and cause this) ?

Comment: Recently I've updated it to latest supported kernel `4.9.35+`, it was `4.9.34+`.. I'll try what you suggested. Thank you

Comment: ... You are welcome , From [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md) i can read : `The HDMI port uses 50mA, the camera module requires 250mA, and keyboards and mice can take as little as 100mA or over 1000mA!` ... so your `1A power supply or 1000mA` can be insufficient if your other connectedd USB devices are keyboard and mouse. Last suggestion: `try with another 1.5A power supply` ?

Comment: You say "latest supported kernel 4.9.35+" **BUT** current Stretch uses 4.19.66+ so it is very out of date. You have not described your networking setup.

Comment: @Ephemeral sorry I forgot to mention that I am facing this only If I connected both wifi adapter and Ethernet usb devices. If I connect only one device it works fine (running without any issue for weeks), is there anyway to check whether is it due to lack to power ?

Comment: Yes with finding your power requirement for all your USB devices and doing some Maths or see my first comment for one physical verification.

Comment: Your problem is unlikely to be power (unless you have a really poor PSU/cable). I run my PiB+ from a 1 A supply.
See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) and also include the contents of any files you have changed.
Also include the output of `ip a` and **WHY** you are using multiple networking interfaces.

Comment: @Milliways , you also use for example keyboard and mice (other connected USB devices) ?

Comment: @Milliways I've updated it using 'apt install raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel', But it only brought me  4.9.35+''. If i explained about I am using this as IPv6 router to use with hurricane electric's tunnel broker since by does not provides native IPv6 connectivity. wlan0 connected to ISP router and eth connected to my PC. everything went well until I try to connect second ISP router via new Ethernet USB adapter

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I am working on get power supply to tryout.

Comment: @Melan **DO NOT** put detail in Comments; edit your question. If you do `sudo apt update  && sudo apt upgrade` it should install the latest software/firmware - assuming you are actually running Stretch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few parameters you could [tweak](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/what-kernel-parameters-are-available-for-fixing-usb-problems) in `/boot/cmdline.txt` back in the day to make USB host more stable (`dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0` and the like). These are mostly useless on modern kernels, as either the underlying causes got fixed or the safe values became the default ones. You can try them out but I wouldn't spend too much time on these, as these tweaks are mostly snake oil by now.

In the remaining cases the prevalent root cause is inadequate power: your USB devices disconnect from the bus for no apparent reason, which (barring internal firmware bugs or hardware problems) is usually due to brown-out resets. If those USB dongles work fine in a laptop using the same firmware, your only option is to get a better power supply or use a second supply to power an external USB hub. Of course, you can't plug the builtin NIC into a laptop, so diagnosing it requires having a second Pi which is unlikely to have the same hardware defect.